# Displaying tweets from user's twitter accounts in an android app

Tags: android, api, twitter, rate-limiting

I am not an experienced developer by an means. I was wondering about the feasibility of being able to take a subset of tweets from my app user's twitter account and displaying them in my android app. I would like to continually update their timeline for a period of 2 hours or so at a time.

When I read the Twitter API documentation, I am not exactly sure as to whether or not I can do this for free. Do you all know if I can do this for free for a bunch of users? Do you also know whether or not there is a limit to how many calls can be made to the Twitter API? If my app were to have say 100,000 users at some point, would all of them calling the API cause me to hit some limit? And again, would that be free?

And then more generally, any responses on how to go about displaying these tweets and what goes into doing this in contacting the Twitter API from the android app would be much appreciated.

Again, I am really inexperienced so I am not really good at interpreting some of the Twitter API documentation. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a web view and an embedded Tweet widget (JS from publish.twitter.com) you could do this for any number of users without hitting limits. If you want to code your own Twitter native display inside your app, you’ll be calling the Twitter API directly, and there are rate limits, but you could always cache the most recent Tweets on your own server, and manage those limits at a single point, rather than having every one of your Android app users sign-in to Twitter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is actually helpful stuff I did not know. For the web view/embedded tweet widget, would it be possible to display tweets from a user's twitter feed (all the people they follow)? Even if some of the people are on private? Or is there another way to do this without hitting a rate limit? Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot embed the user’s “home” timeline (all of the people a user follows). Also, you cannot use embedded Tweets or timelines for protected accounts.

Comment: Can you clarify the Twitter API docs rate limit? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/overview Here it says for just user_timeline and mentions_timeline there is a 100,000 cap. Does that mean no daily cap on home_timeline? Also for the home_timeline, is the only rate limit then: 15 requests per 15 minute window?

Comment: To add to that, is the home_timeline endpoint only user auth rate limited, meaning are there no app auth rate limits? So, I could have 10,000 users making 15 requests in a 15 minute window at the same time = 150,000 requests in 15 minutes?

Comment: That is accurate, but each user must be authenticated.

Comment: awesome thanks, I would upvote your answer as it answers my questions, but I don't have enough reputation